# Longer Blazor File Tab Header Widths?

Tags: blazor, ide

Is there a way to have Blazor file tab-headers adjust their width to suit the file name that's displayed in them... or at least be made to default to a longer width?  I would assume the answer is 'No'... and I certainly wouldn't call this a programming 'emergency'... but it might be helpful to know if there's a way to make this happen.  (Fwiw, I understand that the more Tabs I open the more a Tab Header would need to be 'squeezed' to suit the window.  I'd certainly be able to live with that, but I'm wondering if, prior to that occurrence, the headers can be wider).

Comment: Blazor doesn't have "file tab-headers," so making them longer would be impossible.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I used the wrong term.  When you click on a file in Solution Explorer a window opens up and there's what I chose to call a 'tab' at the top of each file/window you open; where the name of the file is displayed.  If that's not called a "Tab", I apologize.  That said, whatever their name is, it would still be helpful to know if they have a fixed with; or a width that can be adjusted.

Comment: Your question is about Visual Studio, not about Blazor. Use the right tags to attract the right experts.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the tab, and then

[image]

Just set the Maximum tab width as 999. You can have a long file name fully displayed

[image]